# Tomcat unable to parse web.xml, no error at mentioned code point

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using Jersey for my web service, and this is how my web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-name>com.rohanprabhu.external.interfaces.service.web</param-name>
        </init-param>**

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-name>true</param-name>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am getting an error `Occurred at line 10 column 22`, which is where I have marked in my file as '**' (it isn't actually there in the file, I just put it on here). Here is (a part) of the stack trace I get:

```
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert argument: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.convert(IntrospectionUtils.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.CallMethodRule.end(CallMethodRule.java:476)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1057)
    ... 188 more
Occurred at line 10 column 22
Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
```

Here is the entire stacktrace, in case that helps: http://pastebin.com/EX4bMGex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree the error message is suboptimal, but I'm also sure you want one `<param-name>` and one `<param-value>` per `<init-param>`. :-)

Comment: Oh.. yeah.. kind of speechless here. This (sigh).. is the right answer. Nominate for an idiot, and enjoy your rep :\

Comment: @RohanPrabhu However, it is a really really bad error message. And in fact these error messages are what makes JEE development hard...

Comment: I agree.. I guess whatever architecture they have internally might qualify this error statement to have some reasoning behind it, but it is extremely confusing and absolutely does not point the user in the right direction (which is exactly why we stress on Exceptions having messages).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<param-name>` twice. but other init attribute should be `<param-value>`.